# Represent a function as a power series, and find the interval of convergence?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am trying to find the interval of convergence, and represent a function as a power series. I found the interval of convergence to be (-2,2). I have tried both differentiating, and then taking the integral of its results, and going with $$r=\frac{-x}{2}$$
however, I am unable to get the correct answer for the power series representation. The function is:
$$f(x)=\frac{(x - 1)}{(x + 2)}$$
The correct answer is given as:
$$-\frac{1}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{(-1)^n 3x^n}{2^{n+1}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x+2}=\frac{x+2-3}{x+2}=1-\frac3{2-(-x)}=1-\frac{3/2}{1-(-\frac x2)}=1-\frac32\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac x2\right)^n$$

Due to the geometric series, where it converges for $\left|\frac x2\right|<1\implies|x|<2$ by the term test.

Comment: That should do it. +1

Comment: I added what the answer is supposed to be. Yours looks the similar, except it has -1/2 and not 1. Also, how did you notice that the function went into the form 1- (3/2)/1-(-x/2)?

Comment: @Fyree Your answer key moved the 3/2 inside the sum, then it took the $x^0$ out.

Comment: @Fyree And I've updated the answer.  Notice that the second to last step just divides the fraction by $2$.

Comment: I finally get it now. Thank you for the help!